# BootstrapVue - Property or method "data" is not defined... when using scoped slots

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

Hello I'm learning to use BootstrapVue, I copied example from official documentation of BootstrapVue -

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items" foot-clone>
      <!-- A custom formatted data column cell -->
      <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
        {{ data.value.first }} {{ data.value.last }}
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted header cell for field 'name' -->
      <template v-slot:head(name)="data">
        <span class="text-info">{{ data.label.toUpperCase() }}</span>
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted footer cell for field 'name' -->
      <template v-slot:foot(name)="data">
        <span class="text-danger">{{ data.label }}</span>
      </template>

      <!-- Default fall-back custom formatted footer cell -->
      <template v-slot:foot()="data">
        <i>{{ data.label }}</i>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fields: [
          // A column that needs custom formatting
          { key: 'name', label: 'Full Name' },
          // A regular column
          'age',
          // A regular column
          'sex'
        ],
        items: [
          { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
          { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
          { name: { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade' }, sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
          { name: { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge' }, sex: 'Female', age: 62 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

On tutorial page everything seems to work fine but when I run this, I keep getting this: `Property or method "data" is not defined...`
I believe it's because of `<template v-slot:cell(name)="data">` parts somehow doesn't instantiate the data but I don't know why and how to fix it, please help.

Comment: What versions of Vue and BootstrapVue are you running?

Comment: It seems to work fine with me, which version are you using? Could you share your entry point code where yo import Bootstrap-vue?

Comment: You need Vue 2.6.x to use v-slot, and it is also required by Bootstrap-Vue so make sure you have that installed

Comment: Yes I had Vue 2.5.x and that was the problem, ty for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, version was the problem. I was using Vue 2.5.x after I updated it to 2.6.10 it worked without any problem just as in tutorials.